How to improve azcopy performance so that it doesn't clash with other processes?
I manage a server running Ubuntu, which serves as the main backup server with Bacula configured to manage backups for various hosts. Additionally, after each MySQL backup, AzCopy is used to transfer MySQL dumps and InnoDB files to Azure Blob Storage. The command used includes a limitation on the network bandwidth (--cap-mbps 500) because the server's maximum bandwidth is 1 Gbps (this cannot be changed). This limit was necessary as AzCopy operations previously made the server unresponsive.
azcopy cp "$INNOBACKUPEX_DIR" "{{ azure_backup_storage_account }}/mysql-main{{ azure_backup_write_sas }}" --recursive=true --cap-mbps 500 --log-level=ERROR

However, I now encounter a new issue. Centreon, running on a separate host, performs periodic checks on this backup server. When AzCopy operates for extended periods - necessary due to the large size of the MySQL dumps and InnoDB files (over 400 GB) — Centreon often fails to receive responses, triggering alerts. Once AzCopy completes, the server's responsiveness normalizes.
I'm looking for suggestions on optimizing AzCopy's performance to prevent it from interfering with other processes, including Centreon's monitoring activities. Any advice would be appreciated.
Note that I'm running azcopy latest version 10.24.0.
